# Mysql authentication with Active Directory

Tags: mysql, active-directory

I do not understand the following requirement i am to work on.It says--

> Configuration changes are required on the MySQL database server so that the database accounts created for students should authenticate with Active Directory.

I don't understand what it means to authenticate a database with AD? I only understand the scenario in which we authenticate a website application login with AD accounts.

What needs to be done and what would I need for this?

Answer (score -1):

the following posts will help you understand the issue

[stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329963/using-ldap-ad-for-mysql-authenication)

[mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/news-5-5-7.html)

Comment: Hi Kamran,i saw that post.But the concern is i donot understand what the question actually means?

Comment: it means that the mysql server to be configured in a way that users can log in to mysql using their windows login credentials(username and password to login into the windows)